# Why do I get an error as I try to call a procedure?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, procedure

I created a procedure named *greet* as :

```
create procedure greet(message in char(50))
as  
begin 
  dbms_output.put_line('Greet Message : ' || message);
end;
```

The procedure compiled successfully but when I try to call it as :

```
execute greet('Hey ! This is a self created procedure :)');
```

I get an error :

```
execute greet('Hey ! This is a self created procedure :)')
Error report:
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:  
PLS-00905: object SUHAIL.GREET is invalid
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

What error is it ? Why do I get it ?

*Note : 'suhail' is name of the current user connected to oracle server*

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff The value of attribute is `ERROR` ! But earlier it gave the message `compiled successfully`

Comment: :how it is  compiled first?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't believe that your procedure compiled successfully.  When I try to compile it on my system, I get syntax errors

```
SQL> create procedure greet(message in char(50))
  2  as
  3  begin
  4    dbms_output.put_line('Greet Message : ' || message);
  5  end;
  6  /

Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors.

SQL> sho err
Errors for PROCEDURE GREET:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
1/32     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "(" when expecting one of the
         following:
         := ) , default varying character large
         The symbol ":=" was substituted for "(" to continue.
```

If I resolve the syntax errors (you cannot specify a length for an input parameter), it works

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  create or replace procedure greet(message in char)
  2  as
  3  begin
  4    dbms_output.put_line('Greet Message : ' || message);
  5* end;
SQL> /

Procedure created.

SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL> execute greet('Hey ! This is a self created procedure :)');
Greet Message : Hey ! This is a self created procedure :)

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

I would be shocked if you really wanted the input parameter to be declared as `CHAR`.  Almost always, you should use `VARCHAR2` for character strings.  It is exceptionally rare to come across a case where you really want the blank-padding semantics of a `CHAR`.

Comment: what is wrong with `char(50)` ? Why does it produces an error ?

Comment: @SuhailGupta - As I said, you cannot specify a length for an input parameter.  You specify the data type (`CHAR` in this case) as I do in my example.  The length will be based on the length of the parameter that is actually passed in.

Answer (score 1):

this is working dude;

```
create or replace
procedure greet(message in char)
as  
begin 
  dbms_output.put_line('Greet Message : ' || message);
end;
```

see main property  of char datatype is is the length of input data is less than  the size you specified **it'll add blank spaces**.this case is not happened for varchar2.

1. in procedure above mentioned char property is violated so it's *almost treat like varchar2*. so ***if you remove size of input parameter*** it will work and also char support maximum length  of input.